# Vim scripting with Tcl: encoding mismatch

Tags: vim, encoding, character-encoding

I am trying to write a plugin for Vim using Tcl as the backend language. I have written and tested most of the code and it seems to work fine except for one hurdle I can't seem to get over: encoding.

I wonder if someone here is willing to take a test.

Create ~/.vim/plugin/tcltest.tcl with these lines:

```
proc tcl.test   {}  {
    array set CURSOR [[set ::vim::current(window)] cursor]
    lassign "$CURSOR(row) $CURSOR(column)" CR CC
    set bufferCommand [set ::vim::current(buffer)]

    set string "já não bênção"
    puts $string
    $bufferCommand set $CR $string
}
```

Then add these lines to ~/.vimrc:

```
if has("tcl")
    tclfile ~/.vim/plugin/tcltest.tcl
endif
inoremap  ?   ^[:tcl tcl.test<CR>
```

Now relaunch Vim with a new document, go into Insert mode and press '?'

Two things should happen:

1) the string "já não bênção" should be displayed in the message area

2) the string "já não bênção" should be inserted into the buffer

It will look fine in the message area, but it will be all garbled in the buffer because of the accented characters.

There is an 'encoding' command in Tcl and I have tried ALL possible encodings in a foreach loop, but none of them works.

I am convinced that this is a bug, because the string should at least be the same in the buffer and the message area. Even if I am doing something wrong with my Tcl code, the mistake should be reflected in both places.

Can someone please confirm (or not) this and report Vim version and OS/platform?

Comment: Seems to work fine here (manually loaded the tclfile and added the mapping). Debian unstable, console, vim 7.3 patches 1-923 Huge.

Comment: What encoding settings do you have set in vim? What exactly does 'all garbled' mean?

Comment: encoding=latin1, fileencoding= All Garbled means the accented characters become all messy, obviously set to wrong encoding.

Comment: It seems to work for me here when I run with that encoding set up as well so I'm not sure what you are seeing exactly but are those characters even legal latin1 characters? Should this be expected to work at all?

Comment: Yes, they're legal, but not the correct ones. "já não bênção" becomes "jÃ¡ nÃ£o bÃªnÃ§Ã£o". Why wouldn't it be expected to work??? Why isn't the output even the same in the message area and text buffer? They should at least be the same.

Comment: Are you using the utf-8 or latin1 codes for those characters in your script file? Because that might very well make a difference in a latin1 encoding environment. As to why the behaviour of the different parts in vim might differ I'm not sure. But it might have to do with the value of fencs or other encoding options in vim.

Comment: The 'file' command says it is a "ISO-8859 English text". My OS locale encoding is ISO-8859.

Comment: It works for me with a file that says that when I run `vim -u NONE -U NONE -c 'set enc=latin1 fenc= fencs=latin1 nocp'` and then manually run the tclfile and inoremap commands. (Though I also have to set cmdheight=2 to see the messages when I hit ? .) What feature-level of vim are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what feature-level is.

Comment: Huge, Tiny, etc. Shown on the fifth line of the :version output. Also what does the sixth line of that output list for iconv and multi_byte (I don't know if either of those are relevant but it can't hurt to find out.)

Comment: Okay. Huge version with GTK2 GUI, +iconv +multi_byte